# ASP.Net MVC Database Driven Menu Strange HTML output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, subsonic

I have a database driven menu Helper that gets called from within my master page:

```
<div class="topBar">
        <%= Html.MenuTree(39, false, "first", "last") %>    
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Below is the code that outputs my HTML unordered list.  The problem is that sometimes the output of the menu is completely wrong and all over the place ie. sub menu items appear as equal as top menu items.

I cannot find any pattern to why it does it so thought I'd post the code to see if anyone can spot the problem.  My only other thought is that somehow its half cached half called and mixes the output.

This is what it should look like [Correct http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/9317/screenshot20100328at120.png](http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/9317/screenshot20100328at120.png)

Sometimes it comes out like this:[alt text http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/9317/screenshot20100328at120.png](http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/9317/screenshot20100328at120.png)

Here's the code (the boolean IsAdmin is false in this scenario):

```
public static string MenuTree(this HtmlHelper helper, int MenuCategoryID, bool Admin, string firstCssClass, string lastCssClass)
    {

        //TODO: Check for Subsonic fix for UNION bug
        IOrderedQueryable<Menu> menuItems;
        if (Admin)
        {
            menuItems = (from menu2 in Menu.All()
                         join pages in WebPage.All() on menu2.PageID equals pages.ID
                         join pagesRoles in PageRole.All() on pages.ID equals pagesRoles.PageID
                         join roles in aspnet_Role.All() on pagesRoles.RoleId equals roles.RoleId
                         where Roles.GetRolesForUser().Contains(roles.RoleName) && menu2.CategoryID == MenuCategoryID && menu2.Visible
                         select menu2).Distinct().OrderBy(f => f.OrderID);
        }
        else
        {
            menuItems = (from menu2 in Menu.All()
                         join pages in WebPage.All() on menu2.PageID equals pages.ID
                         where menu2.CategoryID == MenuCategoryID && menu2.Visible
                         select menu2).Distinct().OrderBy(f => f.OrderID);
        }

        var nonlinkedmenuItems = (from menu in Menu.All().Where(x => x.PageID == null && x.CategoryID == MenuCategoryID && x.Visible).OrderBy(f => f.OrderID) select menu);

        var allCategories = menuItems.ToList().Concat<Menu>(nonlinkedmenuItems.ToList()).OrderBy(p => p.OrderID).ToList();

        allCategories.ForEach(x => x.Children = allCategories.Where(y => y.ParentID == x.ID).OrderBy(f => f.OrderID));

        Menu home = null;

        if (Admin)
        {
            home = (from menu in Menu.All()
                    join pages in WebPage.All() on menu.PageID equals pages.ID
                    where pages.MenuName == "Home" && pages.IsAdmin
                    select menu).SingleOrDefault();
        }

        IEnumerable<Menu> topLevelItems;
        if (Admin)
            topLevelItems = allCategories.Where(f => f.ParentID == 0 && (f.Children.Count() > 0 || f.ID == home.ID));
        else
            topLevelItems = allCategories.Where(f => f.ParentID == 0);

        var topLevelItemList = topLevelItems.ToList();

        sbMenu.Length = 0;
        sbMenu.AppendLine("<ul>");

        LoopChildren(helper, Admin, topLevelItemList, 0, firstCssClass, lastCssClass);
        sbMenu.AppendLine("</ul>");



        string menuString = sbMenu.ToString();

        //if ((menuString.IndexOf("<li>")) > 0)
        //    menuString = menuString.Insert((menuString.IndexOf("<li>") + 3), " class='first'");

        //if (menuString.LastIndexOf("<li>\r\n") > 0)
        //    menuString = menuString.Insert((menuString.LastIndexOf("<li>\r\n") + 3), " class='last'");

        return sbMenu.ToString();
    }

    private static void LoopChildren(this HtmlHelper helper, bool Admin, List<Menu> CurrentNode, int TabIndents, string firstCssClass, string lastCssClass)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CurrentNode.Count; i++)
        {
            sbMenu.Append(Tabs(TabIndents + 1));
            string linkUrl = "";
            string urlTitle = "";
            if (CurrentNode[i].PageID != null)
            {
                WebPage item = WebPage.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == CurrentNode[i].PageID);
                linkUrl = item.URL;
                urlTitle = item.MenuName;
            }
            else
            {
                linkUrl = CurrentNode[i].URL;
                urlTitle = CurrentNode[i].Title;
            }

            //Specify a RouteLink so that when in Error 404 page for example the links don't become /error/homepage
            //If in admin we can manually write the <a> tag as it has the controller and action in it
            bool selected = false;
            if (helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["pageName"] != null && helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["pageName"].ToString() == linkUrl)
                selected = true;

            string anchorTag = Admin ? "<a href='" + linkUrl + "'>" + urlTitle + "</a>" : helper.RouteLink(urlTitle, new { controller = "WebPage", action = "Details", pageName = linkUrl });

            if (TabIndents == 0 && i == 0 && firstCssClass != null)
                sbMenu.AppendLine("<li class='" + firstCssClass + "'>" + anchorTag);
            else if (TabIndents == 0 && i == (CurrentNode.Count - 1) && lastCssClass != null)
                sbMenu.AppendLine("<li class='" + lastCssClass + "'>" + anchorTag);
            else if (selected)
                sbMenu.AppendLine("<li class='selected'>" + anchorTag);
            else
                sbMenu.AppendLine("<li>" + anchorTag);



            if (CurrentNode[i].Children != null && CurrentNode[i].Children.Count() > 0)
            {
                sbMenu.Append(Tabs(TabIndents + 2));
                sbMenu.AppendLine("<ul>");
                LoopChildren(helper, Admin, CurrentNode[i].Children.ToList(), TabIndents + 2, "", "");
                sbMenu.Append(Tabs(TabIndents + 2));
                sbMenu.AppendLine("</ul>");
            }
            sbMenu.Append(Tabs(TabIndents + 1));
            sbMenu.AppendLine("</li>");
        }

    }

    private static string Tabs(int n)
    {
        return new String('\t', n);
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a PartialView for this?  All that inline string concatenation is painful to read, no wonder why its hard to find the problems. ;)

Comment: yaiks, please no `StringBuilder` for generating HTML! There's `TagBuilder` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that string concatenation for this is painful. TagBuilder is a lot less painful for you.

I didn't check your code for problems, but I imagine that what I would do is basically to take the text output from your helper in a good case and a bad case and run them through a diff tool. Leave some markers before and after the point where you call Html.MenuTree() for debugging purposes - this way you will know exactly where the output starts and stops.

The diff tool will tell you what the differences in the two outputs are. Then you can go looking for the cause of these differences.

Another way I would seriously consider approaching this is through unit testing. Start with a simple unit test giving the MenuTree() method a very simple structure to work with. Verify that the output is sane. Then test more complex scenarios. If you during testing, debugging or in production discover a certain combination of input that causes the problem, write a unit test that tests for the *correct* output. Then fix it. When the test passes, you'll know that you are finished. Also, if you run your tests whenever you change something, you will know that this particular bug will never creep back in.

New bug? New unit test. And so on. Unit tests never solve the problem for you, but they give you the confidence to know that what used to work still works, even when you refactor and come up with cool new stuff.